# how to select only div within parent after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to figure out how to select a particular element with a certain class name within it's parent div, after a click event.

```
<div id="news">
    <div class="one">
        <p>news</p>
    </div>
    <div class="two"> 
        <a href="#" class="clickme"></a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="users">
    <div class="one">
        <p>users</p>
    </div>
    <div class="two"> 
        <a href="#" class="clickme"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

my simple jquery is as follows:

```
$(".clickme").on("click", function () {
//how to select only the element with the class "one" within the parent and show it
});
```

My failed attempts have been trying to use the parents and closest methods and code like `$(this).parents().find(".one").show();`

Any help would be great!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/84bWN/)

try this

`$(this).parent()` refers to `parent` div

`.prev('one')` to previous sibling with class `.one`

```
$(this).parent().prev(".one").show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `.prev()`

```
$(this).parent().prev(".one").show();
```

See the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8EUVs/1/)

Comment: you code was wrong now you end up making similar code to mine lol ..!!

Comment: Actually I forgoted to add `.parent()` for my second ans...After working on demo I noticed that parent was missing....Its my typo that's it...I have no need to copy anyone's code.

Answer (score 0):

I would traverse it like this.

```
$('.clickme').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().siblings().eq(0).show();
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x2k6Q/)